# Scrolling problem with overflowing content

Tags: html, css

I have prepared CSS for modal dialog, but there is a problem. If the content part overflows vertically over the wrapper, the scrolling doesn't work properly.

I can scroll but only in a limited range (I can't get to the beginning of the content).

Where am I going wrong?

```css
.fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Some text

<div class="fade">
  <div class="content">
    Fist line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
    Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Last line
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. If you change this CSS line to `transform: translate(0%, -50%);` the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the content itself positioned `relative` inside of it's `absolute`ly positioned wrapper.

```css
.fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
Some text
<div class="fade">
   <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
         Fist line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>
         Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Text line<br>Last line
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working, thank you. But there's a problem, if the content text is short (that doesn't overflow), the window doesn't align vertically to the center, but on top. Is there a solution for this?